# Get gene location from gene symbol and ID

Tags: r, biomart

I want to get gene location of human genome from gene symbol(example: TTN) and gene ID(example: ENSG00000155657). I want to do it using `biomaRt` package of R. How can I do that?

Comment: You could start by reading the [biomaRt user guide](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/biomaRt/inst/doc/biomaRt.html). Section 4.11 titled "Given the human gene TP53, retrieve the human chromosomal location of this gene..." answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by gene location, but I think the following should get you started:

```
ensembl <- useMart("ensembl")
ensembl <- useDataset("hsapiens_gene_ensembl",mart=ensembl)
getBM(attributes=c('chromosome_name', 'start_position', 'end_position', 'strand'),
      filters=c('hgnc_symbol', 'ensembl_gene_id'),
      values=list('TTN', 'ENSG00000155657'),
      mart=ensembl)
```

You can input more filters by adding additional vectors (of length two in this example) to the `values` list.

You can use the function `listAttributes(ensembl)` to get a data.frame containing all attributes that you can obtain from biomart.

As @neilfws has already stated, the [biomaRt user guide](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/biomaRt/inst/doc/biomaRt.html) is the right place to look for more information about biomaRt.  I recommend that you ask further questions about Bioconductor R packages like biomaRt on the [Bioconductor support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org/).